# How to resolve Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL while creating HTML dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I am dynamically  creating a below  HTML String

I was trying this way ,

by putting \ at the end , but i am getting below error under browser console

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

```
var html = '<div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap1239" data-stuff="[]" data-vegornonveg="vegterian" data-lastwrapquan="0">\
      <div class="prd_title">\
         <h3 class="vegLabel" data-sellprice="12.00" data-sellpricestatic="12.00" data-discprice="0.00" data-discpricestatic="0.00" data-strikeprice="0" data-strikepricestatic="12.00" data-ispercent="0">Pepsi<button style="display:none;" class="btn-d icon-ellipsis prdDiscription ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button></h3>\
      </div>\
      <div class="Itm_left_aside">\
         <div class="Itm_img">\                                                        <img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40" src="images/icon_logo.png">                                                        </div>\
         <div class="Itm_dtsl">\
            <div class="Qty_Wrap">\
               <button class="btn-d icon-minus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>                                                                
               <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input type="text" class="QtyInput" value="2" readonly=""></div>
               <button class="btn-d icon-plus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>                                                            
            </div>
            <button style="display:block;" class="btn-d addonsBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-toppname="Topping" data-crutsname="Crust" data-atrr="1239"><a data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-link">Addons</a></button>                                                        
         </div>\
      </div>\
      <div class="Itm_right_aside" data-percentage="0">\
         <a class="icon-trash-3 deletebtn trashBtn ui-link" style="display: none;"></a>\
         <p style="display:none;">₹ <strike class="strikeprice">24.00</strike> <span style="display:inline-block;" class="tobeappend offRed">₹</span> <span class="discprice offRed">0.00</span> <span class="offRed" style="display:inline-block;">off</span> <span class="offRed" style="display:none;">off</span> </p>\
         <p>₹ <b class="sellprice">24.00</b></p>\
         <p class="additionsclassstyle" style="display: none;"><span>Additions:₹</span>  <b class="additions">0.00</b></p>\
      </div>\
      <div class="Itm_discrp" style="display:none;">\
         <h3>Pepsi</h3>\
      </div>\
   </div>\
   <div style="display: none;" id="addonsWrap1239-placeholder">\
   </div>'

   This is my fiddle ,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9vr6bmpz/1/

Could you please let me know how to resolve this .

Comment: The answer to this one is easy, you keep large strings of HTML **out of your javascript** !

Comment: you have syntax error while creating multi line string in javascript

Comment: OR, add them correctly

Comment: ya i agree that there is a syntax , but i couldn't resolve that .

Comment: You can quite easily figure out the problem by looking at both the syntax highlighting in your example fiddle, and using the JSLint button.

Comment: You can track these error at first place, if using a _smart_ editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9vr6bmpz/4/

```
var html = '<div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap1239" data-stuff="[]" data-vegornonveg="vegterian" data-lastwrapquan="0">\
      <div class="prd_title">\
         <h3 class="vegLabel" data-sellprice="12.00" data-sellpricestatic="12.00" data-discprice="0.00" data-discpricestatic="0.00" data-strikeprice="0" data-strikepricestatic="12.00" data-ispercent="0">Pepsi<button style="display:none;" class="btn-d icon-ellipsis prdDiscription ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button></h3>\
      </div>\
      <div class="Itm_left_aside">\
         <div class="Itm_img"><img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40" src="images/icon_logo.png"></div>\
         <div class="Itm_dtsl">\
            <div class="Qty_Wrap">\
               <button class="btn-d icon-minus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>\
               <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input type="text" class="QtyInput" value="2" readonly=""></div>\
               <button class="btn-d icon-plus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button>\
            </div>\
            <button style="display:block;" class="btn-d addonsBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-toppname="Topping" data-crutsname="Crust" data-atrr="1239"><a data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-link">Addons</a></button>\
         </div>\
      </div>\
      <div class="Itm_right_aside" data-percentage="0">\
         <a class="icon-trash-3 deletebtn trashBtn ui-link" style="display: none;"></a>\
         <p style="display:none;">₹ <strike class="strikeprice">24.00</strike> <span style="display:inline-block;" class="tobeappend offRed">₹</span> <span class="discprice offRed">0.00</span> <span class="offRed" style="display:inline-block;">off</span> <span class="offRed" style="display:none;">off</span> </p>\
         <p>₹ <b class="sellprice">24.00</b></p>\
         <p class="additionsclassstyle" style="display: none;"><span>Additions:₹</span>  <b class="additions">0.00</b></p>\
      </div>\
      <div class="Itm_discrp" style="display:none;">\
         <h3>Pepsi</h3>\
      </div>\
   </div>\
   <div style="display: none;" id="addonsWrap1239-placeholder">\
   </div>'
```

Comment: I  know that this is a stupid question , but being a java developer i dont know this . thanks a lot.